# Best configuration for a multiapp-one db scenario on Jelastic

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jelastic

I'm approaching the deployment of 4 Java webapps that share a common database. I wonder what is the best scenario to do that under the Jelastic platform:

- 5 environments, 5 nodes (4 tomcat and 1 db)
- 1 environment, 5 nodes (4 tomcat and 1 db)
- 1 environment, 2 nodes (1 tomcat managing all the 4 webapps, plus the 2nd node for the db)
- other mixed combinations

Please consider that the webapps need to be served as virtual hosts and share lots of common files on the filesystem, too.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to share filesystem, by far the easiest option would be to use 1 Tomcat instance. Whether or not this is feasible, or creates any additional complications depends on your apps.

So as a general rule of thumb (without in-depth knowledge of your apps and your growth plans etc.), I would suggest 1 Tomcat + 1 database server. You might consider putting them in separate environments though, because that would provide the flexibility to clone either of them (independently) in future, and doesn't really have any significant disadvantages (perhaps small cost variation, depending on your host's pricing structure).

What did your host recommend?

Comment: This will be a brand new installation, so I still have not a current hoster. We're using Jelastic for other applications.
You could be the one :)
The only drawback I see in the 1 Tomcat scenario is that we couldn't be able to restart a single webapp. As far I know, Jelastic is only able to restart the Tomcat as a whole.

Comment: Are there any performance difference accessing the db located in the same or in a different environment?

Comment: DB located in same environment would usually (not guaranteed) be provisioned on the same physical hardware as Tomcat - so access may be very slightly faster, but either case is internal network only. I can't tell you anything about all Jelastic provider's internal networks though. Ours is low latency, but each provider can make their own implementation decisions here.

Comment: I suggest you trial your app on a Jelastic provider and you can test this directly + talk to your chosen hosting providers.